# What is wrong with this simple binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I'm trying to bind a list box in the simplest manner possible with the goal of understanding binding a little better.  All examples I see online show data template, and I don't want to get that complicated yet.  I have a collection of objects.  These objects have a property of string type, and that's what I want to show in the list box.  Below is all the code.  Nothing shows up when I run this.  What am I missing?

```
// The simple object
public class GameData 
{
  public string Team { get; set; }
}

// Window1.xaml
<Grid>
  <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding GameCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Team"></ListBox>
</Grid>

// Window1.xaml.cs file
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
  //public ObservableCollection<GameData> GameCollection;
  // Changed to property per SLaks idea but still no luck
  public ObservableCollection<GameData> GameCollection
  {
    get;
    set;
  }


  public Window1()
  {
    GameCollection = new ObservableCollection<GameData>();
    GameCollection.Add("Tigers");
    GameCollection.Add("Indians");
    GameCollection.Add("Royals");

    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your xaml is invalid "<ListBox> ItemSource" - assuming this is a copy/paste error, and not what your actual XAML looks like.

Comment: That was a typo (typing from a printout).  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some changes I made to get it to work:

```
// The simple object
public class GameData
{
    public string Team { get; set; }
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<GameData> GameCollection { get; set; }

    public Window1()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        GameCollection = new ObservableCollection<GameData>();
        GameCollection.Add(new GameData(){Team = "Tigers"});
        GameCollection.Add(new GameData(){Team = "Royals" });
        GameCollection.Add(new GameData(){Team = "Indians" });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GameCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Team"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I was trying to do everything in xaml and I assumed the DataContext would default to "this".  I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your `GameCollection` field and set the `Window`'s `DataContext` instead.

You can then bind directly to the DataContext using `{Binding}`.

Comment: Still no luck after changing it to a property.

Comment: @bsh152s: He is saying to write something similar to `this.DataContext = GameCollection`.